# How does a folder associate with a document in Workfront?

Tags: attask

Looking in the documents object I see no field for folder ID. The Document Folder object has a collection that will display the documents inside a folder, however I have no idea where this information is stored. I am trying to create a folder VIA the API and then place documents into that folder.

Any help simply identifying which obj/table stores this information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `document` object has a property `isDir` which indicates is it file or directory.

Comment: Thank you, I had previously been under the assumption that DFLDR object held folder information. That said, how do I tell a particular document that it belongs to a particular folder? I would assume that there is some place to load the UID of a document that would link the two.

Comment: @Craig did u get your answer?